# How do I launch an application in a specific virtual desktop with xfwm4?

Tags: xfwm4

I am using Ubuntu with xcfe.

I would like to launch an application - for example, Chromium - in one of the specific virtual desktops offered in xfwm4, with a terminal command.

What command would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The command `wmctrl` works on any desktop. The command `wmctrl -s 1` will activate workspace 2 (wmctrl starts counting from 0). Follow this by the command for launching your application, and you will be there.

To bind that to a hotkey, you can use the construct:

```
sh-c 'wmctrl -s 1 && <yourcommand>'
```